How to fix messed up table dividers in Microsoft Word

As you can see the vertical column dividers are not aligned. How can I "fix" this? Somehow the bottom two rows can only be resized independently of the others above (except row 1, which is broken, too). Stuff like this happens as soon as I  merge cells (see row 1...). I can't reliably let the merged cells span as well…

Not the most elegant way to fix this, but this should work:

Between third and fourth line from bottom (before last "basophile") insert two additional rows.
Copy the text (data) of the last three rows into those new ones, moving each upwards.
Delete the last two rows.

Better would be to simply combine the two tables, but I find the correct spacing of the top might be lost.
